# Scheme Coding Style Questions

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme

I am confused about the Scheme style for my code.

Should I format if forms as:

a.

```
if()
  ()
  ()
```

or b.

```
  if () ()
        ()
```

or c.

```
if () () ()
```

Should I format cond clauses as
a.

```
  cond ()
       ()
```

or b.

```
cond
()
()
```

When do I use a single ; to comment and a double ;;?

Answer (score 7):

[Here](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt) is a Lisp style guide, and [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/computing/classes/cs2360/ghall/style/commenting.html) is a recommended commenting style.

If you have an emacs style editor, typing C-M-q within your s-expression should format it for you; it will get you correctly formatted code if your line breaks are reasonable (and editor configuration for indent-alist hasn't been munged too badly).

Answer (score 6):

To fill in Doug's answer for your specific questions:

```
(if test
    then
    else)

(cond
  (test1 exp1)
  (test2 exp2)
  (else exp3))
```

Or, for conds with long series of expressions:

```
(cond
  (test1
   exp1
   exp2)
  (else
   exp3
   exp4))
```

Comment conventions are a little looser. When I am writing careful code, I do something like this:

```
;;; new section ;;;
;;; section comments


(define (f g . x)
  "docstring goes here"
  ;; in-function comments
  (g x)) ; trailing line comment
```

But the exact boundaries for `;` vs `;;` usage vary. In particular, some people (including me) do not much like trailing line comments and will instead use `;` for in-function comments and `;;;` for section comments.

Comment: Note that most schemes don't have "doc-strings".

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Peter Norvig's ["Tutorial on Good Lisp Programming Style"](http://norvig.com/luv-slides.ps) though you would have found the answer to your particular question in any Scheme/Lisp book.